# Do I need iPhone/iPad specific button images in my case?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, button

Here is my situation:  I have a simple app with some buttons that are images.  I have the image set in xcode using the menu on the right (i simply click the button and pick the image I want from the dropdown).  I created them using a simple image program so they look somewhat glossy and nice, but nothing crazy.  I also sized them for an iphone screen.

Using some auto layout, I've been able to ensure the layout stays the same and the buttons change size with the size of the iphone.  I would like this to be the case with the iPad as well, but I'm worried if they size too big, I'll lose image quality with the button images.  I'm very new to layout and coding and have only been doing this development stuff for a little while.  What are my options?  I figure they are...(and these might not even be possible, throwing them out there):

1) Create two version of the app, one only for iPad and one only for iPhone with different size/quality images for each.

2) Code swift to identify the device and assign the different image accordingly

3) Pick a resolution for the iphone image that when expanded on iPad won't lose much quality

4) I'm overreacting and this isn't a big deal whatsoever since it's just a basic glossy button with some shadowing.

Thank you!  Advice/links appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you run your app in an iPad simulator? Have you checked it with a simulator using the retina version of the hardware?

Comment: I actually played around with it and it doesn't look too bad.  The actual issue seems to be with my scaling/auto layout.  The scaling of the ipad compared to the iphones is more different so it doesn't look as aesthetic as the others.  Maybe I'll make two different apps to spare my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better option to add images for both iPhone(retina/non-retina) and iPad(retina/non-retina). Put the high-resolution and original versions of your image in the same location in your application bundle.

Ones you added images same as the below naming format in to your application resources, the application will automatically pick the right one for you.

`MyImage.png` - Default version of an image resource.

`MyImage@2x.png` - High-resolution version of an image resource for devices with Retina displays.

`MyImage~iphone.png` - Version of an image for iPhone and iPod touch.

`MyImage@2x~iphone.png` - High-resolution version of an image for iPhone and iPod touch devices with Retina displays.

`MyImage~ipad.png` - Version of an image for iPad.

`MyImage@2x~ipad.png` - High-resolution version of an image for iPad devices with Retina displays.

Comment: I did see this solution floating around.  Ramshad, if you could, could you elaborate how to do this?  I'm adding the image in the right toolbar once I have dragged it into the application, so when i choose it from the dropdown I can only choose one.  Not sure how I would add 4 separate ones the way I am doing it.  I'm guessing some coding would be required but I remain uncertain.  Any help would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: And by the dropdown, I mean I click the button and on the right under its properties, I'm just clicking the image part and it lets me choose one image.

Comment: Please read the updated answer, and specify MyImage.png under image part in the dropdown.

Comment: So from what I'm seeing, as long as I keep the "MyImage.png" as the default image, if appropriate, it will take the higher resolution images if they are actually in the resources application.  Hope that's a correct assumption.  Thanks!